# String Filtering .. Any one..Contains only either of the selected characters or both

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a array from 0 to 10000.
problem
And i need to filter only the numbers containing either 3 or 4 or both and none other than that...
eg., 3,4,33,44,333,444,343,434,334

I tried the do while technique but I have made some mistake in the code..\
I'm not getting the output still..:(
the improved code is

```
import java.util.*;
```

import static java.lang.System.*;
public class numb {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num,c,cum;
    int i;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     out.println(3/10);

    out.println("How many elements u need to put in this array?");
    num=in.nextInt();
    int[] ray1 = new int[num];
    List<String> l1 = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (c=0;c<num;c++)
    {


        ray1[c]=c;
    }

            for(i=1;i<num;i++)
            {
         boolean baabu=true;
                do {
                    cum=ray1[i];
                    int lastdig = cum%10;      
                    if(lastdig!=3||lastdig!=4)
                    {
                        baabu=false;
                    }
                    cum=cum/10;
                }
                while(cum>0&&baabu);
                if(baabu)
                {
                    String ad = String.valueOf(ray1[i]);
                    l1.add(ad);
                }



            }
            printme(l1);


}

public static void print (int[] array)
{
    for(int xc:array)
        out.println(xc);
}
public static void printme (List<String> l1)
{
    for(String yc:l1)
        out.println(yc);
}
```

}

Comment: Radix sort technique can be used. Not exactly Radix sort.

Comment: If you find that your code doesn't work when you try to adapt something from an answer, you should read your code very carefully. In particular, what do you think `lastdig!=3||lastdig!=4` evaluates to; and what does the equivalent code in my answer do? (That's not the only problem)

Comment: Btw, don't edit your question to remove your original code. This is simply moving the goalposts, and answers written before the edit no longer make sense. By all means add to the end of the question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the last digit is a 3 or a 4: if it is, divide the number by 10 and check the next digit; otherwise, discard the number.

```
boolean add = true;
do {
  int lastDigit = num % 10;
  if (lastDigit != 3 && lastDigit != 4) {
    add = false;
  }
  num /= 10;
} while (add && num > 0);

if (add) {
  // Add to list.
}
```

Comment: Even more efficient than my solution, nice.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to stackexchange and also java programming..
I didn't know how to take that thread further

your idea worked...
after like 6hrs I'm getting the result.Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Think of the string as a list of characters, eg 3435 is `3,4,3,5` and 39 is `3,9`. You need to iterate over the characters in the string and check that each one is a 3 or 4. Your code checks for specific combinations of 3 and 4 but cannot handle all possible enumerations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're treating the numbers as Strings already, the *simplest* way to find {3,4} strings is by matching the Regex "^[34]+$"

```
Pattern threeFourStrings = Pattern.compile("^[34]+$");
...
if (threeFourStrings.matcher(ad).matches()) {
    l1.add(ad);
}
```

However, since you want *all* {3,4} strings up to 10000 (i.e. up to 4 digits), it would be far more efficient to *construct* them.  You might start looking here: [How to get all possible n-digit numbers that can be formed using given digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645582/how-to-get-all-possible-n-digit-numbers-that-can-be-formed-using-given-digits)

(Of course since you only have 2 digits, "3" and "4", it might be even more efficient to just list the binary numbers from 0 to 1111 and transpose "0" to "3" and "1" to "4".)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for every int in the array (it worked for me):

```
public static String myMethod(int num){

String str = String.valueOf(num);

String ns ="";
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
if (str.substring(i, i+1).equals("3")) 
{
  ns += 3;
}

if (str.substring(i, i+1).equals("4")) 
{
  ns += 4;
}
}
return ns;

}
```